# Is it possible to apply web config transformation during installation of a package

Tags: msbuild, web-config, teamcity, transform, msdeploy

If you have created a package having release1 configuration. and you want to use the same package to push it to live servers but you need to have different web config settings. Is it possible to install that package and also perform web config transformation for various other configurations (LIVE1, LIVE2). Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting your Web.config transformations in a transformation file, you can use Web Deploy parameters.  The parameter values can then be set during package installation either in the IIS Manager UI if you use that to install the package or in a file that you provide with the package if you install it using the command line. For an example, see **Using Deployment Parameters for Web.Config File Settings** in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398068(v=vs.110)

Another option is to use the PackageWeb Nuget package, which is currently a beta release:

http://nuget.org/packages/PackageWeb

PackageWeb is introduced in this blog:

http://sedodream.com/2011/12/24/PackageOncePublishAnywhere.aspx